# Kendo ui Grid shows [object object]

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid, that will only display values like [object object] even if the type is "string". I have the datasource for the grid working with a graph, so I know there is data, and that it should be showing other values.

I'm using MVVM

Datasource:

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "everlive",
            autoSync: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            filter: {
                field: "DeviceID",
                operator: "eq",
                value: device.uuid
            },
            transport: {
                // binding to the Order type in Everlive
                typeName: "BreakPoint"
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        // default Everlive fields
                        CreatedBy: {
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        CreatedAt: {
                            type: "date"
                        },
                        ModifiedAt: {
                            type: "date"
                        },

                        // type fields
                        Energi: {
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        Note: {
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        activity_green: {
                            type: "bool"
                        },
                        activity_yellow: {
                            type: "bool"
                        },
                        activity_red: {
                            type: "bool"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="grid"
                 data-theme="silver"
                 date-scrollable="true"
                 data-pageable="true"
                 data-columns="[
                                 { 'field': 'CreatedAt', template:'#= formatAddress(data) #'},
                                 { 'field': 'Note' },
                                { field: 'Energi', format:'{0:c}'},
                                 { field: 'activity_green', title: 'Grøn Aktivitet', format:'{0:c}'},
                                 { field: 'activity_yellow', title: 'Gul Aktivitet', format:'{0:c}'},
                                 { field: 'activity_red', title: 'Rød Aktivitet', format:'{0:c}'}
                              ]"
                 data-bind="source: ds"
                 style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: I removed some of your code like formatAddress(data) function because i don't know what it does, change your transport into dummy data also your filter. And it works,  here's [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/afiKA)

Comment: that makes no sense to me, tried without the formatAdress first. could it be due to a missing reference to angular ie.?

Comment: @machun - it's like it doesn't process the part that reads data-role="grid" if i remove that, I have the exact same output. The table headers aren't written either - maybe it's a referencing issue?